# How do I store a one-to-many relationship in a database row in SQL?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Here's the use case:

1. I want to set up a database that stores the relationships between a very large number of items.
2. My method is to have two types: nodes (strings) and sets (which contain any number of nodes or other sets or both) which allows for almost unlimited descriptiveness and nuance.
3. I'd like to make it so that by querying the primary key for any item, one can see how it fits into the whole, i.e. what it contains and what other sets contain it.
4. Therefore, I thought about using a four column table:
   a. Key
   b. Human-readable name
   c. Contents (either one string in the case of nodes or a set of keys for the contained items in the case of sets)
   d. Contained-by (a list of keys for the sets that contain this item)

Reading around however, it seems that lists are not a primitive data-type, and, moreover, it seems there is a norm in SQL that one should not store multiple values in a single cell.

I'd love to get your thoughts on, 1. Whether there's a different way to think about my problem such that I can maintain the one-lookup standard for answering the question of how a given item fits into the system without having multiple values in a single cell and 2. If this norm doesn't apply in my case, some nifty ways of approaching this, e.g. a delimited string (I'm reticent about this, as it means doing more data-processing).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to encode the n-m relationship by a custom encoding yourself. That seems counter-productive. SQL databases are explicitly made to represent object relationships. An n-m relationship is typically expressed by a separate link table. If your entities are all of the same type, say a type "node" then in the node table you put an id (primary key) column and whatever content (human readable name) you want to associate with the node in additional columns.
A separate 'edge' table has the links: it could e.g. have columns "source" and "target" if your links are directed where both refer to the id of a node.

Note however: what you describe sounds like a graph, so perhaps a graph database fits better for what you aim at.

Note that an internet search for n-m relationships with SQL should provide you with quite a bit of additional insight as this would be one of the very standard problems.